# How do I get input focus border style back to normal state?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form. Normal state of the border is in color grey. When input/focus it is black (both styled in .css file). When wrong input, the border of the input changes color using jquery:

```
$(inputAdmin).css('border','3px solid red');
```

After clicking a button with the correct input I want the border to go back to normal state.
I used:

```
$(inputAdmin).css('border','3px solid grey');
```

But now the focus don't work. The input field is still grey when typing/focus. How do I change the focus of a input using jquery, or how do I get it back to normal state?

Comment: Instead of adding inline `css()`, use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. Alternatively, if you're using HTML5 validation, just use the `:invalid` selector, eg. `input:invalid { border: 3px solid red; }`

Comment: you can add class on button click and remove that class on focus & apply this css to that class.

Comment: If you insist on using jQuery, set the property to an empty string: `$(inputAdmin).css('border','');`